# KVM switch keyboard / mouse troubleshooting

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mouse

I got this [KVM switch](https://www.jidetech-kvm.com/collections/hdmi-kvm-switch/products/jidetech-2-port-hdmi-kvm-switch-cables-usb-peripheral-sharing-support-4k-2k-30hz-resolution) to switch between a linux based system and a windows system.

I have the following other hardware:

- Very simple keyboard
- Keyboard that also has audio out / in and some additional no standard keys
- very simple wired mouse
- Logitech USB bluetooth mouse with extra buttons

The Windows setup works fine under any combination of the above hardware.

The Linux setup does not reliably work under all combinations:

- simple keyboard / simple mouse: reliably works
- simple keyboard / bleutooth mouse: works for a while but after some time the mouse freezes, if you either unplug or switch to windows and back the mouse starts working again
- complicated keyboard / any mouse: keyboard strokes go on forever and the mouse freezes almost immediately

It's clear to me that:

- The "complicated" keyboard / mouse are causing problems
- Given that the Windows machine works just fine this isn't a KVM problem but a Linux problem.

Result of `uname -a`

```
Linux HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC 4.15.0-91-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 11:09:48 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsusb also shows all peripherals (complicated or not) as I would expect.

Ideally I'd like to use the "complicated" setup but even getting wireless mouse to work would be great.

Not sure what further information to provide, but let me know. Anyone experienced similar issues and figured out a way to fix them?